# Leave only first duplicate entry in bash

Tags: bash, awk

This is my data structure:

```
First   A   1385
First   B   8364
First   C   9734
First   C   9625
Second  A   3566
Second  B   9625
Second  B   0238
```

I what to remove duplicate line entries (information in column 1 and 2) and leave first occurrence of it.
I want to remove: `First    C    9625` and `Second   B    0238` as they are second occurrences of `First C` and `Second B`, for the result like this:

```
First   A   1385
First   B   8364
First   C   9734
Second  A   3566
Second  B   9625
```

What have I tried:

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' FILE  | 
   sort -u | 
   while read LINE; do 
      echo $LINE | 
      tr ' ' '\t' | 
      grep -m1 -F -f - FILE
   done
```

I am just learning bash coding and my solution is very clumsy. I believe that it is possible to do what I want in one bash command.

Comment: `awk '!a[$1$2]++' filename` would suffice.

Comment: @devnull no, that'd fail for some values of `$1` and `$2`. Gregor  any time you write a loop in shell just to process a text file you have the wrong approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '!seen[$1,$2]++' file
First   A   1385
First   B   8364
First   C   9734
Second  A   3566
Second  B   9625
```

Here's why you need the `,` between the fields:

```
$ cat file
ab c
a  bc
$
$ awk '!seen[$1,$2]++' file
ab c
a  bc
$ awk '!seen[$1$2]++' file
ab c
```